# Could not prepare statement (1 not authorized to use function: random)

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, web-sql

Using `Query ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5;`
Gives the error 
Could not prepare statement (1 not authorized to use function: random)

- Is random function supported by chrome websql if yes why I am getting
  such error?
- Do I need permission from the user to use RANDOM() function if so how
  do I obtain it?
- I saw an issue over [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=460191)
- Is this a bug in Chrome?
- Should I start Chrome with some kind of flags on?

`SQLError {message: "could not prepare statement (1 not authorized to use function: random)", code: 5, UNKNOWN_ERR: 0, DATABASE_ERR: 1, VERSION_ERR: 2…}
code: 5
message: "could not prepare statement (1 not authorized to use function: random)"
__proto__: SQLError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `random()` function is not part of Web SQL; you are not allowed to use it.

You have to implement your query differently.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't RAND() work or is it the same thing?

Comment: Rephrased: Did you try RAND() instead of random()